# Set up of a python http web server is hanging

Tags: windows-7, python, webserver, http

I'm attempting to set up a http.server using python (3.85) on a windows 7 PC.
Using [These instructions](https://ryanblunden.com/create-a-http-server-with-one-command-thanks-to-python-29fcfdcd240e)  I paste `python -m http.server 8000` at the command line of my desired directory in a terminal window.
It displays:

```
C:\Server>python -m http.server 8000
Serving HTTP on :: port 8080 (http://[::]:8080/) ...
```

It does this indefinitely. I tried a couple of other port numbers.
I obtained the version using the `python --version` command so it appears to be set up correctly.
Should there be something displayed between the double colons?

Comment: Typically a HTTP server does not quit as this would also end the server. Have you tried if the server can be accessed on the shown port? For the colons see here: https://serverfault.com/q/444554/68215

Comment: Ah, I see. I was expecting it to configure & then return me to the command prompt. It would be helpful if python displayed a notice such as '...server now operational'.  My web pages are now displaying as expected. Thanks. Feel free to convert to an answer, but unfortunately I don't have enough 'reps' to 'up' you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should there be something displayed between the double colons?

No. `::` is simply IPv6 shorthand for an unspecified address (all zeroes) and is the equivalent of `0.0.0.0` in IPv4.

> It does this indefinitely.

This means the web server is running. `http.server` keeps the command prompt open so it can output basic messages regarding server operation to the console.